# Stereo microphone randomly loses one channel

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hardware, microphone

I have a laptop (Acer A515-51G-70PU) with a stereo built-in microphone. Sometimes while I'm using the microphone, the right channel fails and starts recording only noise. This behavior appears to be non deterministic and only gets fixed when I reboot. I have tried reloading Alsa (`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`), but it doesn't work.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Audio device: `Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`

Below is an image where I caught, while recording, the exact moment when the right channel stopped working. The channel above is the left and the channel below is the right.
[image]

The error persists with the use of Jack.

Comment: Boot from a live media and see if it happens there.

Comment: It works for a while and eventually breaks just the same.

Comment: Looks like a strong bias or the noise floor increased sharply.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like problem of hardware, especially even if system is booted from live media do the same.

1. I suppose your microphones are placed on a display part of your PC. Sometimes cables or connectors connecting the display to body of PC are partially damaged/disconnected. Try to tilt display down and up, press some places on display frame and watch the situation. If problem occurs in relation to mechanical influence (moving, pressure) then it is probably cable/contact problem.
2. I suppose your microphones are electret type. They need DC voltage supply in operational state. There are more situations which can break microphone functionality in PC. Eg. if voltage is disconnected, short-circuited, connected to higher than operational voltage power source, pre-amplifying FET transistor in microphone fails...  A curved signal line in your perfect snapshot shows DC voltage jump which is shaped by removing of the DC component of voltage to wave (by capacitor). It looks like some kind of electrical shock, i.e. short circuit or voltage disconnecting. The second possibility is more probable in case you listen noise after that.

The PC reboot you mentioned disconnects power supply of some internal components for short moment. Possible explanation of operational status restoration is: A failed part (FET transistor etc.) recovers its state and start working again.

Sorry, I cannot give you more exact information. But I suppose it is HW problem concerning your microphone, either in cabling or in electronic parts.